# import-csv Cmdlet with Hashtag as First Character

Tags: csv, powershell

I have two csv files I want to compare, but when I try to use the import-csv cmdlet, Powershell won't do it properly (different for each file, but both are wrong).  After troubleshooting, I realized the problem is that both files start with a '#'.  If I remove this, the cmdlet works fine.  However, I don't want to massage the csvs every time I do this task.  Is there a way around this?

Here's the error one gives me:

```
    Import-Csv : The member "' '" is already present.At line:1 char:1
+ import-csv("\\dshfs03.dgoz.dccz.ccnz\psst\Aram\RTCA Merge\ctvl.csv")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

The cmdlet works on the other file, but it just skips the first line all together, leaving the second line as headers.

I've tried using get-content to first remove them, but when I export the edited files, they're not in proper form anymore.

Comment: Please add some sample contents from the files and describe desired and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the behavior of `Import-Csv` so your options are:

- Process the file yourself (`Get-Content`, `-split`, etc.)
- Replace the `#` in code and then use `Import-Csv`/`ConvertFrom-Csv`
- Use properly formatted files from the start

Comment: I used get-content to edit, easy enough.  However, when I export the edited file using export-csv, I'm left with a csv file consisting exclusively of objects and lengths; all the data I actually cared about is gone.  How can I edit my csv, then export a nice, formatted csv, data intact?

Comment: Got it! First, used outfile, which kept the data, then import csv reformatted it properly... not an elegant solution, but it works

Comment: @Errorum instead of piping to `Out-File` and then using `Import-Csv`, try piping directly to `ConvertFrom-Csv` and avoid having to write an intermediate file.

Comment: Wow, that made a lot of difference in run speed.  Thanks for the help!